# prepareForSegue method after search

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, segue

I have implemented search functionality in my project and it works fine, but the problem is that I dont know how to pass correct data for detailViewController after searching.

My searching method looks like this:

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@", searchText];
    NSMutableArray *filteredArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self.allItems filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
    self.sortedArray = filteredArray;

    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

And prepareForSegue method looks like this:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showEvielasDetails"]) {

        NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

        EvielasDetailViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];

        detailViewController.eVielas = [[Evielas alloc] initWithIndex:path.row];

    }
}
```

I have created separate class which handles data passing to detailViewController as per below:

```
- (instancetype) initWithIndex:(NSUInteger) index {

    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        EvielasLibrary *eVielasLibrary = [[EvielasLibrary alloc] init];
        _library = eVielasLibrary.library;

        NSDictionary *eVielasDictionary = _library[index];

        _eVielasNumurs = [eVielasDictionary objectForKey:kEviela];
        _eVielasNosaukums = [eVielasDictionary objectForKey:kNosaukums];
        _eVielasIespPielietojums = [eVielasDictionary objectForKey:kIespPielietojums];
        _eVielasIespIedarbiba= [eVielasDictionary objectForKey:kIespIedarbiba];

    }
    return self;
}
```

And my data structure looks like this:

```
- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _library = @[@{kEviela : @"E100",
                           kNosaukums : @"Kurkumīns",
                           kIespPielietojums : @"Krāsviela",
                           kIespIedarbiba : @"Drošs"},
                         @{kEviela : @"E101",
                           kNosaukums : @"Riboflavīns",
                           kIespPielietojums : @"-",
                           kIespIedarbiba : @"Drošs"},
                         @{kEviela : @"E102",
                           kNosaukums : @"Tartrazīns",
                           kIespPielietojums : @"Konditorejas izstrādājumi ,atspirdzinošie dzērieni, augļu sulas, marinēti dārzeņi, marcipāns, sausās zupas, siera cepumi, saldā kukurūza. \nLietošana citur: kosmētika, vilnas un zīda krāsa.",
                           kIespIedarbiba : @"Drošs"}...
```

The problem is that when I am not searching data everything works fine because indexPath are matching with Array but as soon as I am starting searching indexes do not match and detailViewController shows me wrong details.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The Problem here is that when you are searching some text and you are not accessing the selected data from filteredArray, istead you are accessing it from `EvielasLibrary *eVielasLibrary = [[EvielasLibrary alloc] init];` `_library = eVielasLibrary.library;`  `NSDictionary *eVielasDictionary = _library[index];`  which is the original array which you use to filter out results

Comment: So in case of search how can I access data for my selected cell?

Comment: you should fetch you dictionary like this so that you get your results correctly    `NSDictionary *eVielasDictionary = self.sortedArray[index];
        _eVielasNumurs = [eVielasDictionary objectForKey:kEviela];
        _eVielasNosaukums = [eVielasDictionary objectForKey:kNosaukums];
        _eVielasIespPielietojums = [eVielasDictionary objectForKey:kIespPielietojums];
        _eVielasIespIedarbiba= [eVielasDictionary objectForKey:kIespIedarbiba];`

Comment: I have amended my dictionary as You informed but any way I am getting result only from original array index 0. I am not sure what is going wrong in my code.  I have amended like this: if (searchViewController.totalSortedArray.count > 0) {NSDictionary *eVielasDictionary = searchViewController.totalSortedArray[index]; ... }else {NSDictionary *eVielasDictionary2 = _library[index];....} and in segue method I left the same detailViewController.eVielas = [[Evielas alloc] initWithIndex:path.row]; I think it should work but I am not sure why it is not working.

Comment: at which part of your code are you calling this segue `"showEvielasDetails"` which `method`

Comment: In this method: -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showEvielasDetails"]) {

        NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

        EvielasDetailViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];

        detailViewController.eVielas = [[Evielas alloc] initWithIndex:path.row];

    }
}

Comment: This method is protocol method that ios calls whenever a segue is triggered, I would like to know when is this segue called.

Comment: In case if Segue is connected from button in StoryBoard, It will automatically be triggered when the button is pressed. otherwise you will have to programatically call it using `performSegueWithIdentifier:`

Comment: Yes, it is connected in storyboard and it works but the only problem is that it always shows me details from my original library and shows details of index0

Comment: Can You please give me Your skype or whatsApp, so we can solve this please. That would help me a lot.

Comment: Can not reach You in skype, did You received my invitation request in skype?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any data which you are passing to your detail viewcontroller. For that create an global object in detailVC and assign it in your prepareForSegue method accessing it with the help of viewcontroller instance and pass it.

Answer (score 0):

Then you have to store value globally from **didSelect** method of **UITableViewDelegate** before triggering segue and then pass it in detailVC.

Comment: Can You please help me and show how it should be done? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As @priyam suggested, try this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  self.globalVar = self.sortedArray[indexPath.row]
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
  if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showEvielasDetails"]) {
    EvielasDetailViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
    detailViewController.eVielas = //create Evielas object using self.globalVar

  }
}
```

Comment: Still I am stuck with this, I have created a gobalVariable and trying to pass correct details to detailView, so now it looks like this but detailViewController.eVielas = [self.totalSortedArray objectAtIndex:path.row]; but it crashes when I am trying to search saying that unrecognized selector is sent

Answer (score 0):

Use code as follows after giving an identifier to your segue:

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let dataModel = DataModel()
        dataModel.addOnArray = []
        dataModel.dataDict = mainArray[indexPath.section] as! [String : String]
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "gotoDetailVC", sender: dataModel)

}


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "gotoDetailVC" {
        let detailVC = segue.destination as! ExpandDetailViewController
        detailVC.data = sender as! DataModel
    }
}
```